# Convergence of the series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\left(\sin\frac{1}{n^n}\cdot 2^n\cdot n!\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the series 
$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\left(\sin\frac{1}{n^n}\cdot 2^n\cdot n!\right)
$$ 
converge?

Comment: Does $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2^n n!}{n^n}$$ converge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $0<\sin n^{-n}<n^{-n}$ for $n\ge1$.  Thus,

$$0<\sin (n^{-n})2^n\,n!<\frac{2^n\,n!}{n^n}$$

Now, invoke Stirling's formula

$$n!=\sqrt{2\pi n}(n/e)^n\left(1+\frac{1}{12n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)$$

We now see that

$$0<\sin (n^{-n})2^n\,n!<\frac{2^n\sqrt{2\pi n}}{e^n}<3n\left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^n$$

Since

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}3n\left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^n=\frac{6e}{(e-2)^2}$$

then

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\,\sin (n^{-n})2^n\,n!<\frac{6e}{(e-2)^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does. We have:
$$ n! \leq \frac{n^{n+1}}{e^n} \tag{1}$$
(prove it by induction) so that:
$$ 0\leq \frac{2^n n!}{n^n} \leq n\left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^n \tag{2}$$
and our series is convergent by comparison with:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1} n\left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^n =\frac{2e}{(e-2)^2}.\tag{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: If you know the Stirling approximation
$$
n!\sim C(n/e)^n,
$$
you know that the series behaves as $\sum (2/e)^n$.